# Forms - Add a picture to every item in a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How do I add pictures to a ListView in C# Forms?
My program gets all subfolders of a directory and is able to display the names in a ListView.
But I am having trouble adding a folder icon to each listview Item.
This is the code I have tried so far:

```
string storedir = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + 
"\\myfolder";

ImageList imgl = new ImageList();
//Get the folder icon from resources
imgl.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.folder);

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(storedir);
foreach (DirectoryInfo getdirs in dir.GetDirectories("*.*")) {
    ListViewItem lItem = listView1.Items.Add(getdirs.Name, imgl.Images.Count - 1);
}
```

No success tho:

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

It works now. Thanks to @Gusman and @LarsTech !
I added an ImageList Control to the form and named it "imgl". Then I set it as Small- and LargeImageList on the ListView control and finally I removed

`ImageList imgl = new ImageList();`

Thank you!

Comment: The index of the image must be based on 0, so instead of `imgl.Images.Count` use `imgl.Images.Count - 1`

Comment: The ListView control needs to reference your image list through the LargeImageList and SmallImageList properties.

Comment: Okay I added the " - 1" but that alone didn't change anything (also updated the post) and @LarsTech both options, Large and SmallImageList won't allow me to choose anything. It simply says "(none)"

Comment: ADDITION: I added an ImageList control and named it imgl. It works now! Thank you! :)

Comment: images up to 256x256 can be added with a imagelist. For larger images you need to go for ownerdrawing the listview. - If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lars said in comment, you have to set `LargeImageList` property to a reference of imagelist

so, assign image list like this:

```
listView1.LargeImageList = imgl;
```

next, you have to add 0-based index of your image. In your imagelist 0 means first image, 1 second etc. Something like this (no need to access last image in list by specifying last index):

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo getdirs in dir.GetDirectories("*.*")) {
    ListViewItem lItem = listView1.Items.Add(getdirs.Name, 0);
```